# Unable to find specific value from array with indexOf method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my array :

```
$scope.Statistics = [];
```

This statistics array contains records like below :

```
['Usa'] : regions: 
          [0] : name : 'chicago'
          [1] : name : 'miami'
          [2] : name : 'alaska'
          [3] : name : 'washington'
```

This is my loop :

```
<tr ng-repeat="region in Statistics[currentRegion].regions">
   <a data-ng-click="Myfunc(region.name)">
   </a>
 </tr>

$scope.currentRegion = 'Usa';
 $scope.Myfunc = function (region) {
        $scope.currentIndex = $scope.Statistics[$scope.currentRegion].regions.indexOf(region);
        console.log($scope.currentIndex); // -1
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
>   can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

How do I find respective region from this statistics array?

Comment: Please **search thoroughly** before posting, this question has been asked and answered many, many times. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : But i am trying to find value using indexof method.ofcourse i have research on this before posting question here but i couldnt able to find answers which uses indexof method

Comment: There's a reason for that: `indexOf` is the wrong method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually much simpler to get the index of the object itself since reference is same

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :So could you please tell me that how dis is duplicate question of what you posted the link.Its getting really harder and harder to ask questions on SO nowadays :)

Comment: Pass in the whole object...not the `name` property

Comment: @charlietfl : you mean region and not region.name?

Comment: Yes... that is what you are trying to index

Comment: @Learning: Read the answers there: You use a loop, or `Array#find`, or `Array#findIndex`, ...

Comment: @charlietfl's "pass in the whole object" will work **if** it's the **same** object (not just an equivalent one). If it's the exact same object (not just another object with the same properties), you're right, this isn't a duplicate of the other. But I don't think it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is the same reference, OP is iterating the same array in the view and has access to each element in the array as `region`

Comment: @charlietfl: I defer to you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the whole object and get the index of that object in the array.

You are trying to get the index of an object's property in the array but the array contains whole objects

Change to

```
<a data-ng-click="Myfunc(region)">
```

Or you already have access to the index using `$index` within `ng-repeat` so long as you aren't using any filtering on the original array

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.I agree i made a mistake but why i get 4 downvotes.You see this this question as duplicate?

Comment: Not really a duplicate in this case since you already have access to the object reference and don't need to search the whole array to match that property

Comment: Yeah that is why i am frustrated with this downvotes.Since i showed my efforts and clearly explain this question.still i got 3 downvotes.It is really getting harder and harder nowadays to ask questions on SO because I dont know which questions will be welcomed and which not :)

Comment: Are you here to solve the problem or worry about votes? There was a misunderstanding about how angular works by a very high rep and respected user and it was simply crowd mentality...don't worry about it

Comment: No actually i dont worry about votes but this downvotes make chances very less of getting answers and users shows less interest when question is downvoted.Apart from that this points are usefull in case of starting bounty on any question and as i already have very less points and i get points only by asking question and not like you giving lots of answers that is why i worry when i got downvotes on question :)

Comment: But you got the answer in comments before the votes were cast and then it was re-opened as a result of those comments and got a proper answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132571/discussion-between-learning-and-charlietfl).